# How to calculate the last day of the month?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

I am having issues with the calculation of when the next Last Day of the Month is for a notification which is scheduled to be sent.

Here is my code:

```
RecurrenceFrequency recurrenceFrequency = notification.getRecurrenceFrequency();
Calendar nextNotifTime = Calendar.getInstance();
```

This is the line causing issues I believe:

```
nextNotifTime.add(recurrenceFrequency.getRecurrencePeriod(), 
                  recurrenceFrequency.getRecurrenceOffset());
```

How can I use the Calendar to properly set the last day of the next month for the notification?

Comment: Set it to the first day of the next month and then roll back one day.

Comment: A [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would make it easier to answer this question. What problem are you actually seeing?

Answer (score 388, accepted):

```
Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

This returns actual maximum for current month. For example it is February of leap year now, so it returns 29 as `int`.

Comment: thanks, I need to get the max for the next month however, also it still has to work that it can be the first day of the month as well, as that part works now.

thanks again for your time and effort

Comment: It is not a problem to get `ActualMaximum` for every date. Just roll calendar instance to required date before calling `getActualMaximum`. The first date can be obtained by `getActualMinimum()`

Comment: ok thanks so much Alex, so if I wish to roll the instance to a month ahead and find out the getActualMaximum for that month how would I do so??
cheers

Comment: would this be it Alex?

nextNotifTime.roll(Calendar.MONTH, true);                                nextNotifTime.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Comment: also I set the ready date time after this:
`nextNotification.setReadyDateTime(nextNotifTime.getTime());`

therefore should I not do this instead:
`nextNotifTime.roll(Calendar.MONTH, true);
                                    nextNotifTime.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                                    nextNotifTime.setTime(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

?

Comment: @OakvilleWork You can use the add method of the Calendar class to roll the calendar instance ahead by a certain number of months, using the MONTH constant and give the amount of months. Like so: calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1)

Answer (score 75):

## java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()

Using the `java.time` library built into Java 8, you can use the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) interface. We find an implementation ready for use in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) utility class: [`lastDayOfMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html#lastDayOfMonth()).

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); //2015-11-23
LocalDate lastDay = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()); //2015-11-30
```

If you need to add time information, you may use any available `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` conversion like

```
lastDay.atStartOfDay(); //2015-11-30T00:00
```

Comment: Good Answer. But that last part is weak, suggesting the use of `LocalDateTime`. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot determine when a particular day in a particular place actually starts. That class only works for plain generic 24-hour days, not real-world days. For real days, specify a time zone: `ZonedDateTime zdt = now.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ) ;`. Some days in some places may start at a different time, such as 01:00, because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Answer (score 40):

And to get last day as Date object:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

Date lastDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 22):

You can set the calendar to the first of next month and then subtract a day.

```
Calendar nextNotifTime = Calendar.getInstance();
nextNotifTime.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
nextNotifTime.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
nextNotifTime.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
```

After running this code nextNotifTime will be set to the last day of the current month.  Keep in mind if today is the last day of the month the net effect of this code is that the Calendar object remains unchanged.

Answer (score 20):

Following will always give proper results:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, ANY_MONTH);
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, ANY_YEAR);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);// This is necessary to get proper results
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Why it's necessary? Could you tell me :)

Comment: Yep, just had tests fail for this exact reason above. The problem is that unless DAY_OF_MONTH is set, it will default to current.

Comment: You should set (DAY_OF_MONTH, 1) first.
If you are on 31th of January and set month to February it will skip to March, because the 31th of February does not exist.

`Calendar cal = DateUtils.getCalendar(2021, 1, 31); // DateUtils is custom.
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.FEBRUARY);
System.out.println(cal.getTime());`

>>> Wed Mar 03 00:00:00 CET 2021
@mike

Answer (score 11):

You can also use YearMonth.

Like:

```
YearMonth.of(2019,7).atEndOfMonth()
YearMonth.of(2019,7).atDay(1)
```

See
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#atEndOfMonth--

Answer (score 10):

Using the latest `java.time` library here is the best solution:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate endOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
```

Alternatively, you can do:

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = date.withDayOfMonth(date.lengthOfMonth());
```

Answer (score 3):

Look at the `getActualMaximum(int field)` method of the Calendar object.

If you set your Calendar object to be in the month for which you are seeking the last date, then `getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` will give you the last day.

Answer (score 2):

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = sdf.parse("11/02/2016");

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
        calendar.setTime(date);  

        System.out.println("First Day Of Month : " + calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));  
        System.out.println("Last Day of Month  : " + calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin date extension implementation using `java.util.Calendar`

```
fun Date.toEndOfMonth(): Date {
    return Calendar.getInstance().apply {
        time = this@toEndOfMonth
    }.toEndOfMonth().time
}

fun Calendar.toEndOfMonth(): Calendar {
    set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
    return this
}
```

You can call `toEndOfMonth` function on each Date object like `Date().toEndOfMonth()`

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting these legacy classes in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: It is not a bad advice. The modern _java.time_ is available for Android only for API 26+. We still depend on _java.util.*_ when supporting (not so) old devices.