# How to set a repeat alarm for every month on first and last day of month?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to implement alarm for every month first day and every month last day. How can I implement that and how can I pass it to the alarm class?

### Code

```
Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);


        }
    };

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {
        System.out.println("alram class");



        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 60000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way is to create two listeners and register them for starting of month and end of month. The start and end of month can be set on a Calendar object using `set` method of Calendar class.

As shown on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation)

Comment: Thankyou,can you provide any link for  selected week days.

Comment: You will find documentation on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: Is any database is required for alarm

Comment: No, You don't need database for alarms