# How does Calendar class calculate months?

Tags: java, datetime, time

I got a really annoying problem with calendar class. I have two JTextFields to enter a period of date (txtStart & txtEnd). If start date begins at the first day of month (01.), I set the end date to "last day of month".

Now the user can change change the period by clicking a plus or minus button, then I want to increase or decrease only the month of start & end date.

```
Calendar tempStart = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar tempEnd = Calendar.getInstance();

    if (txtStart.getText().trim().startsWith("01.")) {
      System.out.println("get dates typed by user, and set \"last day of month\" to txtEnd");

      tempStart = convStringToDate(txtStart.getText().trim(), false);
      System.out.println(tempStart.getTime() + "  #+#+###++ ");

      tempEnd = getLastDayOfMonth(txtStart.getText().trim());
      System.out.println(tempEnd.getTime() + "  #+#+###++ ");

      System.out.println("  ");

      System.out.println("multi is either +1 or -1, increasing or decreasing only the month !");

      tempStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, tempStart.get(Calendar.MONTH) + multi);
      System.out.println(tempStart.getTime() + "  #+#+###++ ");

      tempEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH, tempEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH) + multi);
      System.out.println(tempEnd.getTime() + "  #+#+###++ ");

      System.out.println("  ");
    }
```

My methods are working correctly. Now I got some bewildering output.

If I enter 01.11.2015 at txtStart (dd.MM.yyy) I got following output:

```
get dates typed by user, and set "last day of month" to txtEnd
Sun Nov 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Mon Nov 30 23:59:59 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 

multi is either +1 or -1, increasing or decreasing only the month !
Tue Dec 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Wed Dec 30 23:59:59 GMT 2015  #+#+###++
```

Looks pretty nice and everthing seems to work correctly, but if I enter 01.10.2015 at txtStart (dd.MM.yyy) I got following output:

```
get dates typed by user, and set "last day of month" to txtEnd
Thu Oct 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Sat Oct 31 23:59:59 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 

multi is either +1 or -1, increasing or decreasing only the month !
Sun Nov 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Tue Dec 01 23:59:59 GMT 2015  #+#+###++
```

May anyone have an idea why my end date is wrong at output 2.

EDIT:
multi = +1 or -1 (see in output1 or output2 comment)

```
private Calendar getLastDayOfMonth(String sDate) {
  Calendar cal = convStringToDate(sDate, true);
  // passing month-1 because 0-->jan, 1-->feb... 11-->dec
  //    calendar.set(year, month - 1, 1);
  cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, MAX_ZEIT[0]); //  23
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, MAX_ZEIT[1]);  //  59
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, MAX_ZEIT[2]);  //  59
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, MAX_ZEIT[3]); //  0
  //    Time: 23:59:59:0

  return cal;
}
```

##############      SOLUTION:    ####################.

```
    if (txtStart.getText().trim().startsWith("01.")) {
      tempStart = convStringToDate(txtStart.getText().trim(), false);
      tempEnd = (Calendar) tempStart.clone(); // set the date somewhere at the same month ( e.g. at start date )

      tempStart.set(Calendar.MONTH, tempStart.get(Calendar.MONTH) + multi); // inc- or decrease the month first
      tempEnd.set(Calendar.MONTH, tempEnd.get(Calendar.MONTH) + multi); // inc- or decrease the month first ( now there is no overflow due to the 30th or 31th day )

      tempEnd = getLastDayOfMonth(df2.format(tempEnd.getTime())); //  finally setting the "last day of month" 
    }
```

The solution is to do first of all to increase or decrease the month, after that I can set the last day of month without getting any overflow problems.

Output:

```
get dates typed by user, and set "last day of month" to txtEnd
Thu Oct 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Thu Oct 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 

multi is either +1 or -1, increasing or decreasing only the month !
Sun Nov 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Sun Nov 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 

 FINALLY 
Sun Nov 01 00:00:01 GMT 2015  #+#+###++ 
Mon Nov 30 23:59:59 GMT 2015  #+#+###++
```

I thank you all for your help !!!

Comment: Also you might be interested in JSpinner (see SpinnerDateModel and set calendarField to Calendar.MONTH) to increase/decrease date.

Comment: I guess we need to look at `getLastDayOfMonth()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [last day of month calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation)

Comment: It'll be even worse doing this with 01.02.2015. You need to be clear about what "one month later" means, and what start data and end date indicate. A duration of one entire month (no matter how long) is better identified without giving the days of the month explicitly.

Comment: This is exactly what I´m trying to do! I convert a String (01.11.2015) into a Calendar object, then I want to increase the month by using the Calendar specific methods. Where is the problem? I didn´t do anything strange with a "String date" or something else....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end date is incorrect in the first example, as well. It shows 30/12 whereas the last day of December is the 31st. When you add +1 to the month you don't check whether the following month has the same number of days.

November has 30 days. Therefore, incrementing October 31st gives November "31st" which is actually December 1st.

Lots of programmers need to do arithmetic on dates. That's why java.util.Calendar class has a method add() that you can use that encapsulates all the calculations you need. Check the JavaDocs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)

Comment: oh you´re right! I haven´t noticed this before. Thank you, maybe I found a solution, but it´ll be a little bit laborious...

Comment: @prototype0815 No, it isn't laborious at all.

Comment: Thank you, your answer showed me the right direction for a solution!

Comment: @prototype0815 I'm really glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

After you have incremented or decremented the month of the start date, use

```
int lastDayOfMonth = startDate.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

and use startDate in combination with day-of-month set to this value as the endDate.

```
Calendar sd = new GregorianCalendar( 2015, 1, 1 );
int last = sd.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Calendar ed = new GregorianCalendar( sd.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                                     sd.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                     last );
System.out.println( sd.getTime() + " " + ed.getTime() );

sd.add( Calendar.MONTH, 1 );
last = sd.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
ed = new GregorianCalendar( sd.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                            sd.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                            last );
System.out.println( sd.getTime() + " " + ed.getTime() );
```