# java.util.date getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

Tags: java, date

Having an issue with getting the maximum days in a month using Java Date.   The below code works fine except certain days of the year.   I have not found a pattern.   On August 31, 2016 it returned 1 for the maximum days in September and November.   Today it works fine.   Is there something I need to modify in the code to get this behavior to stop?

```
int lastDay;
int lastWeekDay;

public Integer getLastDate(int month, int year) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd");
    return Integer.valueOf(DATE_FORMAT.format(date));
}
```

Comment: Answer can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation

Comment: Can you post your attempts in code? Are you sure you set the right month, i.e. 7 for August?