# Generating a Jasper report at the end of the month

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

We're creating a report scheduling tool where user can select "monthly recurrence" and then provide day of the month that the report is generated.  We're planning to use Jasper SOAP/REST APIs to trigger the report generation.  Our problem is how to handle the case when user enters 29, 30 or 31?  Our desired behavior would be for Jasper Server to adjust the generation date to the month end if the date does not exist for that month. For example user chooses 31, if month does not have a 31st, then report should be generated on 30th or 28th,29th for February.
Could this be done?

Comment: Do you need solution with help of *JR Server* only?

Comment: We can do it on client side or server side whatever works/easier

Comment: In this case you use sheduller (quartz or just cron). See also how to get last day of month with Java: [last day of month calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9397203/876298)

Comment: So client will always create a schedule every month?  How about the server side solution?