# How to get last day of the month for the given date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a given date:

```
01/10/2017(mm/dd/yyyy)

Calendar c = c.getInstance();

c.setTime(date);
```

Now to point to the last day of the month I am using the following code:

```
c.set(Calendar.Date, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.Date));
```

> Expected Output : 01/31/2017
>
> Original Output : 02/01/2017

I am not getting the expected output. Its returning me the first day of next month.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: For the record: please look into using *markup* when putting code into your postings; dont put in everything as ordinary text!

Comment: And please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 16):

You better use the new date time features of Java 8 here:

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2000, Month.OCTOBER, 15);
LocalDate lastOfMonth = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
System.out.printf("last day of Month: %s%n", lastOfMonth );
```

Yes, you could theoretically also use Calendar objects and do all kinds of low level operations yourself. But chances are: you will get that wrong ... well, unless you look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation) and follow the advise from there.

But as Basil is correctly pointing out: The 310 project is pretty close to java.time (because the later was designed to match the former); and 310 can be "ported" [back](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) to Java7. So if there is more than one place where you need to deal with dates, I would look into exactly that: making your life easier by using the "sane" date/time library.

Comment: Actually I am developing in Java 7 environment.

Comment: Then I would say: that DUP that was pointed out should be answer all your questions.

Comment: See the [**ThreeTen-Backport**](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project for a back-port of much of the java.time functionality for Java 6 & Java 7. Further adapted to Android in the ThreeTenABP project

Comment: @BasilBourque Great idea; thanks, included that in my answer and showed my gratitude ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I have doubts about mm/dd/yyyy. Try this

```
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("01/10/2017");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(d);
c.set(Calendar.DATE, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

it gives expected date:

Tue Jan 31 00:00:00 EET 2017