# Is there any Scala function that gives last date of the month that date belongs?

Tags: scala, date, calendar, java-time

this is my first question on stack overflow.
I have a date as input and output should be last date of the month that falls in.

for example

Input string "01/15/2023" should output "01/31/2023" or
"02/10/2021" should output "02/28/2021" 0r

"02/10/2024" should output "02/29/2024"  (Incase of leap year) etc all such rules applicable.

I have tried below code through online search of a java , but I am getting error which I am not able to figure it out, please do help me out.

```
val endDate: ZonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2023-01-15")
       println("1A. Last day of the current month: "+endDate.toLocalDateTime().with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-a-given-string-date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488658/get-last-day-of-month https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41697143/how-to-get-last-day-of-the-month-for-the-given-date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34076518/calendar-get-last-day-of-previous-month

Comment: Your idea is right. Use `LocalDate` for a date. A `ZonedDateTime` would have required that you have got time of day and time zone, so is the wrong class here. Other than that your code should work.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to parse dates in a `ZonedDateTime` will not work like that because you are lacking the time zone information. I will use a `LocalDate`, which more closely models the input, and leave the conversion from `LocalDate` to `ZonedDateTime` as a separate problem.

Regardless, you can use the `with` method on both types and pass `java.time.TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth` as in the following example:

```
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters

def t(date: String): java.time.LocalDate =
    java.time.LocalDate.parse(date, java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))

val tests = Map(
  t("2023-01-15") -> t("2023-01-31"),
  t("2023-09-15") -> t("2023-09-30"),
  t("2024-02-14") -> t("2024-02-29"),
  t("2023-02-14") -> t("2023-02-28"),
)

for ((input, expected) <- tests) {
  val actual = input.`with`(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())
  assert(actual == expected, s"$actual did not equal $expected for input $input")
}
```

Notice I had to put the call to `with` between backticks because `with` is also a keyword in Scala.

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/kQOlOJ3xQeOi5L2tIVBtMA).

You can read more about `with` [here on its JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), which also points to how to use it together with `TemporalAdjuster`s.

Answer (score 0):

```scala
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters

val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")

val date = LocalDate.parse("02/10/2021", formatter)

val endDate = date.`with`(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth())

println(s"last date of month = ${endDate.format(formatter)}")
```