# Why Calendar.getActualMaximum does not work

Tags: java, calendar

I want to get the max date of one month, that it's does't work in some day like the code, it's appear by condition as below
February has problem 2017 Feb Max is 28，If your computer's date is larger than 28, like 2017-03-29 or 2017-04-30

```
Date date = PrimeUtil.formatStringToTime("2017-02","yyyy-MM");
System.out.println(date);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR,date.getYear());
c.set(Calendar.MONTH,date.getMonth());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [last day of month calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation)

Comment: Date.getYear and Date.getMonth are deprecated for a reason.  Use [Calendar.setTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTime-java.util.Date-) instead.

Comment: Improve English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem by myself,I flow the resource code find that If put February, and use c.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth()) that the GregorianCalendar have return a wrong time, it's maybe a bug of Calendar, I change my code like below, it will work well

```
Date date = PrimeUtil.formatStringToTime("2017-02","yyyy-MM");
System.out.println(date);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(date);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,c.getActualMaximum(c.DAY_OF_MONTH));
System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

the console will print:

```
Wed Feb 01 00:00:00 CST 2017
Tue Feb 28 00:00:00 CST 2017
```

It's looks like cause by the mythod c.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());

Comment: The problem is that the date is a milliseconds number, so when you set the month, you add some millis to the time. if you expect the 31/04, in milliseconds this date is 02/04.

Answer (score 5):

I had your problem. The problem is that when you set the month, the day is shifted if needed.

I had a method:

```
public static Date getLastDayOfMounth(int month){
    Calendar cTemp = Calendar.getInstance();
    // here is where I need to set the day
    cTemp.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    cTemp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cTemp.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    return cTemp.getTime();
}
```

I had a test unit for the method that test the method for each month, from 0 to 11. It has workt until today.

Today, 29 March 2018, the test case gone on error for february... why?

First cTemp  = 29/03/2018 (today)

then `cTemp.set(Calendar.MONTH, 1);` is 29/02/2018 but this day does not esists, so became 01/03/2018

then `cTemp.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)` is the last day of march.

I solved adding

```
cTemp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

before setting the month. So I start always from first day, avoid problem of skipping to the next month.

Comment: This. If you wonder why your tests are failing *now*, check your current date. (I'm writing this comment on the 30th, as tests for february are suddenly failing).

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't changing `DAY_OF_MONTH`, so as the current date is 29 March 2019, even I change month to February, but in 2019, February has only 28 days, so even after changing month to Feb, it was still considering March, to resolve this I have to set `DAY_OF_MONTH` to 1.

```
private fun getLengthOfMonth(year: Int, month: Int): Int {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1)
        return calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your case: the value of date is "2017-02", the value of c is: "2017-03-30"

```
date: 2017-02
c: 2017-03-30

c.set(Calendar.YEAR, date.getYear());
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, date.getMonth());
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

=>

```
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2017);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 2);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 31);
```

Here set 31 to DAY_OF_MONTH, Which could not get what you expected!

Another case: 
the value of date is "2017-04", the value of c is: "2017-03-31"

```
date: 2017-04
c: 2017-05-31
```

When we set 31 to DAY_OF_MONTH, we will not get what we expected.

Comment: your answer print the value,but not point why the getMonth() return 30, so bad!O(∩_∩)O~

Comment: @Shake.Yong   if c is 2017-04-30, then c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) will be 30; if c is 2017-03-30 then c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)  will be 31

Comment: The result of getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) depends on the month of Calendar.

Comment: the API c.set(Calendar.MONTH,2) ,cannot work well on the condition what I said!

Comment: ,Only February have this problem