# How to loop through each month of current year and get first and last date of each month

Tags: java, calendar

I wanna loop through all the months of a given year or current year and get first and last date of each month.
For example. Current year is 2017 and month October. So i wanna loop from October, 2017 to Decemeber, 2017 and fetch first and last date of each month like october first date is 2017-10-01 and last date will be 2017-10-31.

Comment: explain your question with programming efforts

Comment: Hint: if you can possibly use `java.time`, it'll be a lot nicer than using `java.util.Calendar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting last day of the month in given string date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13624442/getting-last-day-of-the-month-in-given-string-date)

Comment: without calendar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720245/336511

Comment: possile duplicates of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397203/last-day-of-month-calculation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By using Calendar (works in all Java versions) :

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        cal.clear();
        cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

        for (int currentMonth = month; currentMonth < 12; currentMonth++) {

            cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, currentMonth);

            //first day :
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            Date firstDay = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println("firstDay=" + firstDay);

            //last day
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            Date lastDay = cal.getTime();
            System.out.println("lastDay=" + lastDay);
        }
```

By using new Java 8 date/time API :

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
        int month = date.getMonthValue();

        for (int currentMonth = month; currentMonth <= 12; currentMonth++) {
            date = date.withMonth(currentMonth);

            //start of month :
            LocalDate firstDay = date.withDayOfMonth(1);
            System.out.println("firstDay=" + firstDay);

            //end of month
            LocalDate lastDay = date.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth());
            System.out.println("lastDay=" + lastDay);
        }
```

**EDIT JAVA8+**

Another aproach to this could be:[Documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/java-iterate-date-range)

```
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.*;//to get functions firstDayOfMonth() and lastDayOfMonth()
...
LocalDate initialdate= ...
LocalDate localDateNow = ...
DateTimeFormatter format1 = ...

for(LocalDate date = initialdate; date.isBefore(localDateNow); date = date.plusMonths(1)) { //Could be plusdays if you want to interate day by day

    LocalDate dtini = date.with(firstDayOfMonth());
    LocalDate dtend = dtini.with(lastDayOfMonth());
    //LocalDate dtend = dtini.plusDays(14); //If you want from day 1 do 15

    //TODO: Use dtini and dtend to your like
    System.out.println("dtini =" + format1.format(dtini));
    System.out.println("dtend =" + format1.format(dtend));

}
```

Comment: Good Answer. You could get a little fancier by replacing that `for` loop to use the `Month` enum with an `EnumSet`, and `YearMonth` rather than `TemporalAdjuster`: `for ( Month month : EnumSet.range( today.getMonth( ) , Month.DECEMBER ) )`  See example [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/G4BwY6)

Comment: you're welcome to edit my post :)